# Is there a Python to Whitespace language converter?

Tags: python

I am having trouble finding one because "Whitespace" is a common word, but I'm curious if this can be done. Thanks.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't have lists, dictionaries, or objects. I don't think such a converter would be affordable to write...

Comment: I tried, but I honestly couldn't think of a more useless thing than a python to whitespace converter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing -- it would require the whole Python language to be running in Whitespace - so that your Python program culd use functions, lists, and other built-ins, not to mention the standard library.

Such a thing could be achievable via Pypy - you could write a Whitespace backend -- An effort I doubt could find funding or support.

However, a "one man hack" to get there might be changing the Python byte-code ops to use only whitespace charaters. It would not be "whitespace compatible" - but you would have the same effect in the end: compiled Python files - those we know as "pyc"s could be composed of Whitespace only for the code. (but not for the data and meta-data markup), hacking a couple of  files in the Python source tree.

Changing the opcodes themselves is easy - they are in the Lib/opcode.py file in a Python Source tree - but you would have to change the interpreter to work with multi-byte opcodes (as currently all opcodes are one byte+ parameters).

Comment: A whitespace backend for PyPy's translation toolchain would be just as practical as implementing any other real-world language in whitespace. That is, absolutely and entirely impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such program to my knowledge, but there are tools for Whitespace written in Python:

- [Whitespace Assembler](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577108-whitespace-assembler/)
- [Whitespace Helpers](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577109-whitespace-helpers/)
- [Whitespace Interpreter](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577110-whitespace-interpreter/)
- [Whitespace Stack Calculator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577112-whitespace-stack-calculator/)
- [Whitespace Memory Manager](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577673-whitespace-memory-manager/)